# NHibernate - SQL Server CE - Delete Cascade not working

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sql-server-ce, hql, cascading-deletes

I have two tables:

- Receipt
- ReceiptJournal

`Receipt` has 0...n `ReceiptJournals`

The mapping for this (in `Receipt`) looks like:

```
this.HasMany(x => x.ReceiptJournals).AsSet().Fetch.Select().Inverse().Cascade.Delete();
```

The underlying database which I use is  SQL Server CE 4.0.

Now, when I execute a delete-statement

```
const string sql = "delete from Receipt where IsFinished = 0 and IsParked = 0";
var query = NHibernateHelper.CurrentSession.CreateSQLQuery(sql);
query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

I get an exception:

> Could not execute native bulk manipulation query:delete from Receipt
>   where IsFinished = 0 and IsParked = 0[SQL: delete from Receipt where
>   IsFinished = 0 and IsParked = 0]
>
> System.Exception {NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException}
>
> [System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException]  {"Der Primärschlüsselwert
>   kann nicht gelöscht werden, da noch Verweise auf diesen Schlüssel
>   vorhanden sind. [ Foreign key constraint name =
>   FK_Receipt_ReceiptJournal ]"} System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException

Does NHibernate with SQL Server CE not support cascade delete or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()`. It's a timing problem, NHibernate is attempting to delete from Receipt first but can't because of the foreign key constraint. Setting the cascade strategy to AllDeleteOrphan() will cause it to delete the ReceiptJournal records first because they will be orphaned.

Comment: when I change it to `AllDeleteOrphan` or `DeleteOrphan` I still get the same exception.